# SQL query to get running total for records matching condition over last 12 months

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to query a table and get a running total for each of the last 12 months. A record could fall in more than one month if the range of two date fields falls on multiple months. The fields are DueDate and DeferralDate.

So for example, lets say I have the following 4 records:

```
Id | Date1      | Date2
1    01/20/2020   05/29/2020
2    02/01/2020   08/14/2020
3    04/01/2020   04/30/2020
4    07/08/2020   12/31/2020
```

My result would look like this:

```
Nov 19 | Dec 19 | Jan 20 | Feb 20 | Mar 20 | Apr 20 | May 20 | Jun 20 | Jul 20 | Aug 20 | Sept 20 | Oct 20
0        0        1        2        2        3        2        1        2        2        1         1
```

I have no idea how to go about this other than 12 separate queries but there's probably a better way to do it I'm unaware of. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this in columns, then it is conditional aggregation.  Assuming you want any overlap in the month:

```
select sum(case when date1 < '2019-12-01' and date2 >= '20190-11-01' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_201911,
       sum(case when date1 < '2020-01-01' and date2 >= '20190-12-01' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_201912,
       sum(case when date1 < '2020-02-01' and date2 >= '2020-01-01' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_202001,
       sum(case when date1 < '2020-03-01' and date2 >= '2020-02-01' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_202002,
       . . .
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

Select sum(count(date1) , count(date2)) ,
Format(date1,'MMMyy')
from tablename
Where month (date1) = month (date2)

Then you have to use Pivot to horizontalize the select result